# Further titlesec/etoc customization

Tags: titlesec, etoc

I've the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoc}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\scshape\roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont}
  {\scshape\thechapter}
  {0pt}
  {}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont\itshape}
  {}
  {1em}
  {}

\titlespacing{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{3cm}

\etocsetstyle{chapter}
{}
  {\leavevmode\leftskip 0cm\relax}
  {\llap{\parbox[t]{1.5cm}{\mdseries\hfill\etocpage}\hspace{.5cm}}%
    \normalsize\parbox[t]{1cm}{\quad\etocnumber\hfill}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1cm-15pt\relax}{\etocname\par}\hfill\par
  }
  {}
\etocsetstyle{section}
  {}
  {\leavevmode\leftskip 0cm\relax}
  {\llap{\parbox[t]{1.5cm}{\mdseries\hfill\etocpage}\hspace{.5cm}}%
    \normalsize\parbox[t]{1cm}{\quad\etocnumber.\hfill}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1cm-15pt\relax}{\etocname\par}\hfill\par
  }
  {}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\section{Section Three}
\section{Section Four}

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\section{Section Three}
\section{Section Four}
\section{Section Five}

\chapter{Chapter Three}
\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\section{Section Three}

\end{document}
```

However, I'd like to make two changes:

1) page numbers and chapter/section number right aligned, and not left aligned as from the present code

2) a little `vspace` before each chapter line in the Table of content.

How is it possible to produce these results? Always in etoc code? Thanx

ADDENDUM
The result I'd like to have is as in the following pic:

[image]

Comment: Do you use the `twoside` option?

Comment: Yes. Not in the present MWE, but in my original file I use `report` class with `twoside` option

Comment: So I suppose you want the page number to be on the outer side, rather than on the right side. Is it the same for chapter titles – unless you use the option `openright`?

Comment: My both questions are related to Table of contents, not about headers... In fact my above code is relative only to Toc

Comment: Oh! I misunderstood your query: I thought both table of contents and headers/footers were concerned. I don't know `etoc`, I only use `titletoc` to customise tables of contents. Sorry I can't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The modifications

```
\etocsetstyle{chapter}
{}
  {\addvspace{2ex}\leavevmode\leftskip 0cm\relax}
  {\llap{\makebox[1.5cm][r]{\mdseries\etocpage}\hspace{.5cm}}%
    \normalsize\makebox[1cm][r]{\etocnumber\phantom{.}}\hspace{10pt}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1cm-27pt\relax}{\etocname\par}\hfill\par
  }
  {}
\etocsetstyle{section}
  {}
  {\leavevmode\leftskip 0cm\relax}
  {\llap{\makebox[1.5cm][r]{\mdseries\etocpage}\hspace{.5cm}}%
    \normalsize\makebox[1cm][r]{\etocnumber.}\hspace{10pt}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1cm-27pt\relax}{\etocname\par}\hfill\par
  }
  {}
```

Basically, I changed the `\parbox`es to `\makebox`es with `r` (right alignment) and added a convenient vertical skip (`2ex`, in my example, but use any value to suit your needs) in the third mandatory argument for `\etocsetstyle` for chapters.

The complete code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoc}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\scshape\roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont}
  {\scshape\thechapter}
  {0pt}
  {}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont\itshape}
  {}
  {1em}
  {}

\titlespacing{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{3cm}

\etocsetstyle{chapter}
{}
  {\addvspace{2ex}\leavevmode\leftskip 0cm\relax}
  {\llap{\makebox[1.5cm][r]{\mdseries\etocpage}\hspace{.5cm}}%
    \normalsize\makebox[1cm][r]{\etocnumber\phantom{.}}\hspace{10pt}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1cm-27pt\relax}{\etocname\par}\hfill\par
  }
  {}
\etocsetstyle{section}
  {}
  {\leavevmode\leftskip 0cm\relax}
  {\llap{\makebox[1.5cm][r]{\mdseries\etocpage}\hspace{.5cm}}%
    \normalsize\makebox[1cm][r]{\etocnumber.}\hspace{10pt}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1cm-27pt\relax}{\etocname\par}\hfill\par
  }
  {}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\section{Section Three}
\section{Section Four}

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\section{Section Three}
\section{Section Four}
\section{Section Five}

\setcounter{page}{99}% just for the example

\chapter{Chapter Three}
\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\section{Section Three}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Wonderful!! If I don't need the page number for chapters, for they begin with section 1, I can use `\etocsetstyle{chapter}
{}
  {\addvspace{2ex}\leavevmode\leftskip 0cm\relax}
  {\llap{\makebox[1.5cm][r]{\mdseries\phantom\etocpage}\hspace{.5cm}}%
    \normalsize\makebox[1cm][r]{\etocnumber\phantom{.}}\hspace{10pt}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1cm-27pt\relax}{\etocname\par}\hfill\par
  }
  {}` -- However, If I'd like to have in any case the page number for Bibliography (which is a \chapter*), can I add some specific code?

Comment: @user41063 since this is not directly related to the issue discussed here, I think the best thing to do would be to open a fresh new question.

Comment: ok, I posted the new question at the following link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228350/customizing-titlesec-etoc-further-answer